# How to switch to `flycheck-list-errors` buffer/window/minibuffer?

Tags: buffers, window, flycheck, cycling

For starters I use Doom Emacs.

Here's the scenario:

I have a python/perl/js buffer and flycheck-mode activated. Flycheck does its job and tells me that there are some errors that need attention. I go and do `M-x flycheck-list-errors (or SPC c x). I have 2 spaces now: One with my code (which I believe is a window) and another **something** (buffer/window/minibuffer?) with the list of errors.

Question is: How do I switch to that **something** without using the mouse?

I've tried `next-buffer`, `previous-buffer`, `C-x o`, and I simply don't know how to focus on it.

Appreciate your help as It's driving me crazy! It shouldn't be that hard, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use M-x `other-window` to switch to the other window or create a custom function to use instead of the default function `flycheck-list-error`. The following function opens the `flycheck-list-errors` buffer and switches to it.

```
(defun switch-flycheck-list-errors ()
(interactive)
(flycheck-list-errors)
(pop-to-buffer "*Flycheck errors*"))
```